# Swift: implement a protocol variable as a lazy var?

Tags: swift, lazy-evaluation

It seems that it's not possible to implement a variable that's required by a protocol, with a lazy variable. For example:

```
protocol Foo {
  var foo: String { get }
}

struct Bar: Foo {
  lazy var foo: String = "Hello World"
}
```

Compiler complains that `Type 'Bar' does not conform to protocol 'Foo'`.

It's also not possible to add the `lazy` keyword in the protocol declaration, since then you get `'lazy' isn't allowed on a protocol requirement` error.

So is this not at all possible?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Citing [the Language Guide - Properties - Lazy Stored Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) [*emphasis* mine]:

> A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value *is not
>   calculated until the first time it is used*.

I.e., the value is *mutated* upon first usage. Since `foo` has been blueprinted in the `Foo` protocol as `get`, implicitly `nonmutating get`, the value type `Bar` does not fulfil this promise with its `lazy` property `foo`, a property with a `mutating` getter.

Changing `Bar` to a reference type will allow it to fulfil the `Foo` blueprint (as mutating a property of a reference type doesn't mutate the type instance itself):

```
protocol Foo {
    var foo: String { get }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    lazy var foo: String = "Hello World"
}
```

Alternative, specify in the blueprint of the `foo` property of `Foo` that it has a `mutating` getter.

```
protocol Foo {
    var foo: String { mutating get }
}

struct Bar: Foo {
    lazy var foo: String = "Hello World"
}
```

---

See the following Q&A for some additional details of the `mutating`/`nonmutating` specifiers for getters and setters:

- [Swift mutable set in property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423595/swift-mutable-set-in-property/37424121#37424121)